# no module found when calling lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to run a python program on PySpark 1.6. The script below is using a module called "dateutil" to convert time from one timezone to another timezone. I've checked that dateutil module is installed on all worker nodes and the current system I am using to submit the job.

Exec command:

```
spark-submit --packages "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0" test.py
```

Script:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Row, functions, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import os, sys
import logging
import subprocess
import math
import csv
import functools
import pickle
from operator import add
from itertools import chain
import argparse
import hashlib
import cStringIO
import time
import copy
import datetime
import pytz

conf = SparkConf ()
conf.set('spark.kyroserializer.buffer.max', '32000')
conf.set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf, appName = "Testing dateutil...")
sqlContext = HiveContext (sc)

def utcToAESTDateString (row):
    #import pytz
    from dateutil import tz
    utc_tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('UTC')
    #utc_tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row["start time (unix time)"].decode())).replace(tzinfo=utc_time)
    #print(utc_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    aest_time = dateutil.tz.gettz('AEST')
    math.acos (1)
    #print(utc_time.astimezone(aest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    #aedt_time = tz.gettz('AEDT')
    #print(utc_time.astimezone(aedt_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    #return utc_time.astimezone(aedt_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return Row(sdate = unicode(utc_time.astimezone(aest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), "utf-8")) + row

sqlContext.createDataFrame(sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='false', quote='"')\
    .load("/user/xxx/conviva/*")\
    .filter("`start time (unix time)` <> '' AND `start time (unix time)` IS NOT NULL")\
    .rdd\
    .map(lambda y: utcToAESTDateString(y)))\
    .registerTempTable("table1")


#sqlContext.sql ("""select * from table1 left join fixed_dart on table1.`_1` = fixed_dart.`_4` and table1.`_18` = fixed_dart.`_1`""").show()
sqlContext.sql ("""select * from table1 limit 10""").show()
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.2-1.cdh5.8.2.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.2-1.cdh5.8.2.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.2-1.cdh5.8.2.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.2-1.cdh5.8.2.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1293, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "/home/xxxx/test.py", line 50, in <lambda>
  File "/home/xxxx/test.py", line 34, in utcToAESTDateString
NameError: global name 'dateutil' is not defined

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Try putting this import statement on top (instead of inside the func definition)
from dateutil import tz

Comment: @SuryaAvala I've tried what you suggested and the result is the same.

Comment: Do you have dateutil installed?

Comment: I have checked it on the worker nodes by running "import dateutil" using pyspark and python and they both work without any errors.

Comment: Ah got it! Once you import something like 
from dateutil import tz
you can't do dateutil.tz when you are using tz again.
you can just do tz

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines `utc_tz = tz.gettz('UTC')`
and `aest_time = tz.gettz('AEST')`

So when you import a specific method like this:
`from dateutil import tz` and you can't do a function call like `dateutil.tz`
You have to do `tz()`.

Your code should be as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Row, functions, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import os, sys
import logging
import subprocess
import math
import csv
import functools
import pickle
from operator import add
from itertools import chain
import argparse
import hashlib
import cStringIO
import time
import copy
import datetime
import pytz

conf = SparkConf ()
conf.set('spark.kyroserializer.buffer.max', '32000')
conf.set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf, appName = "Testing dateutil...")
sqlContext = HiveContext (sc)

def utcToAESTDateString (row):
    #import pytz
    from dateutil import tz
    utc_tz = tz.gettz('UTC')
    #utc_tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row["start time (unix time)"].decode())).replace(tzinfo=utc_time)
    #print(utc_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    aest_time = tz.gettz('AEST')
    math.acos (1)
    #print(utc_time.astimezone(aest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    #aedt_time = tz.gettz('AEDT')
    #print(utc_time.astimezone(aedt_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    #return utc_time.astimezone(aedt_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return Row(sdate = unicode(utc_time.astimezone(aest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), "utf-8")) + row

sqlContext.createDataFrame(sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='false', quote='"')\
    .load("/user/xxx/conviva/*")\
    .filter("`start time (unix time)` <> '' AND `start time (unix time)` IS NOT NULL")\
    .rdd\
    .map(lambda y: utcToAESTDateString(y)))\
    .registerTempTable("table1")


#sqlContext.sql ("""select * from table1 left join fixed_dart on table1.`_1` = fixed_dart.`_4` and table1.`_18` = fixed_dart.`_1`""").show()
sqlContext.sql ("""select * from table1 limit 10""").show()
```

Comment: I am still having issue. Here is the error: `File "/home/dat.nguyen/test.py", line 32, in utcToAESTDateString
ImportError: No module named dateutil`

Comment: what is your line 32? is it this utc_tz = tz.gettz('UTC')?